# 2dimensional array operation

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

What is the correct code to do this:

a new method called `calculatePercentage` with parameters `int exam[][] int percentages[]` and returntype `void`?

The method has to calculate all the percentages which have been stocked in `int exam[][]`. The objects stored in this `exam[][]` are results on /20. The percentages have to be on /100.

Thank you very much because I have no idea that works.

How the data in exam[][] is inserted

```
private void insertExamResults(int array[][])
    {
        int[] exam = new int[3];
        for (int teller = 0; teller < 3; teller++)
        {
            int i = 0;
            exam[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Exams of student " + teller + " (max = 5)"));
            i++;
        }
    }
```

The new method I wrote:

```
public void calculatePercentage(int exam[][], int percentages[])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                //code for the sum of all elements on row
                            //stock this new value in a new array percentages[]
            }
    }
```

The double array exam has 3 rows and 5 colums.

Comment: I just don't know how to start with double arrays :(

Comment: You shouldn't accept an int[], but rather, return it

Comment: How is data stored inside the exam array?

Comment: @user1873613 Is this homework?

Comment: the data in exam[][] is stored like this:

private void insertExams(int array[][])
 {
  int[] exam = new int[3];
  for (int teller = 0; teller <= 3; teller++)
  {
   int i = 0;
   exam[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Examen of student " + teller + " (max = 5)"));
   i++;
  }
 }

Comment: @smit, this isn't homework, it's an ex i found in our textcourse. I'm just preparing for the coming exam.

Comment: 2D Arrays are exactly like regular arrays...Think of it as an array of arrays. In regards to it being out of 20 and needing to be out of 100, multiple each value by 5.

Comment: @user1873613 better you put this in your question, you can edit that question any time. Its completely unreadble here. Moreover if its homework SO will help you to give you gi=uidlines to approch this

Comment: Sorry everyone, I only know Java since 3-4 months.
I really try to increase my skills.
@smit: classes are finished, this was an ex we didn't/couldn't make.

Comment: In insertExamResults(int array[][]) method where and how is the parameter array[][] used? Why is your exam represented as two dimensional arrays? Teller has values 0,1,2,3 but exam can take in only 3 values since you declared it as int[3]. Post the question exactly like how it is described in your textcourse so that someone can help you with it.

Comment: @SerotoninChase: I saw the mistake of teller, now it should have the values 0,1,2. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < 8; i++)
   for (int j=0; j < 8; j++)
      board[i][j] = i+j;
```

Comment: thanks David Ruan!
I will try this, but I can see that it is something like this.

Comment: So it should look like the method in the above section?